# How to test local sites in Metro IE10?

Tags: windows-8-preview, internet-explorer-10

Has anyone found a way to enable local subnet sites in the Metro version of IE10? Currently, if I try to access a site in my subnet block, e.g. http://192.168.1.50/index.php, I just get the error "Internet Explorer cannot display this web page.".

One workaround would be to use our public IP and NAT specific ports for each of the servers, but this would be a hassle. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried adding a hosts file mapping but result was no different than typing url by ip address...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature appears to be by design, as explained in this blog post:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506172214/https://web.archive.org/web/20160206145918/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx)

One way to deal with it (works for me), is to manually add the site to the Local Intranet.

Comment: Also works to add it to trusted sites.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way in the Metro interface, but if you hit the wrench icon next to the URL and click "View on the desktop," it'll load the "good old fashioned" IE10 browser and that will load up local IP-based URLs just fine.

Comment: Not much help if the whole point is to test the sites in metro mode...

Comment: @robertc Immersive and desktop IE use the same engine. You can enable EPM in desktop IE to make them behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the site WAN-accessible and access it via a proxy, then it should be no different from accessing a WAN site. Installing a personal certificate on each browser you intend to test the site on should allow you to transparently deal with the security issues. Otherwise, you can restrict access to the IP of the proxy you're using.

Alternatively, you could just add an IP outside your subnet to the web server's NIC and have the webserver bind to that IP.