# Accessing local sites from IE10 Metro mode

Tags: windows-8-preview, localhost, parallels, mamp, internet-explorer-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test local sites in Metro IE10?](https://superuser.com/questions/396989/how-to-test-local-sites-in-metro-ie10)

I've just installed the Windows 8 Consumer Preview to test my websites in IE 10.

I'm running the Win8CP in a virtual machine in Parallels 7, on my MacBook Pro (OS X Lion 10.7.2).
I haven't installed Parallels Tools because Win8 won't let me (that's for another SO question...)

I've added the addresses I need to test (sites running on my Mac using MAMP) to my hosts file, pointing to my Mac's IP address on Parallels' virtual network.

In Internet Explorer on the desktop, all works fine. (Yay! :-)

*However*, **in Metro mode Internet Explorer won't open any of my local sites**.
I simply get a message saying "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

Nor does it work just going straight to my Mac's IP address, though this does work in IE on the desktop.

This seems to be a restriction in IE metro mode preventing "localhost" type access - though technically I guess this isn't actually localhost.

I've tried adding the site names to the trusted sites list; and this *does* work - but I have to do it for every site.
Also, I guess this changes settings which might make sites perform differently from real life, so it's not totally desirable from a testing point of view.

So, does anyone know how to get around this annoying restriction?

For what it's worth, the addresses I'm trying to access are all in the form http://address.dev/